# Update input name attribute without eq()

Tags: jquery, refactoring

I add row number at the end of the name dynamically using code below for the request parameter to be unique.

```
$("#myTable").find("tr").each(function() {
    var text = $(this).find("td input:text");
    var select = $(this).find("select");
    var cb = $(this).find("td input:checkbox");
    select.eq(0).prop("name", select.eq(0).prop("name") + counter);
    text.eq(0).prop("name", text.eq(0).prop("name") + counter);
    text.eq(1).prop("name", text.eq(1).prop("name") + counter);
    cb.eq(0).prop("name", cb.eq(0).prop("name") + counter);
});
```

Is there a way to reduce my code above rather than specifying `eq()` or `index` even though I set on different types of input (text, checkbox) and select.
Does anyone can introduce me to a more simple and short approach on this? Any help is so much appreciated.

Comment: HI @Rayon , i also set not only for the first input field.

Comment: Provided answer seems perfect for this use case...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `:input` selector will retrieve all inputs, so you don't need separate clauses for the `select` and checkboxes. From there you can negate the need for the `each()` loop by providing a function to the `prop()` method which accepts the current value as a parameter which you can append to. Try this:

```
$('#myTable :input').prop('name', function(i, v) {
    return v + counter;
});
```

If you need to increment the `counter` variable then you would still need the `each()` loop, although you could automate it by using the index of the current `tr` like this:

```
$('#myTable tr').each(function(tr_i) {
    $(this).find(':input').prop('name', function(inp_i, v) {
        return v + tr_i;
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi @Rory, Thanks for your code. My issue for the code you suggest,  it's appending counter again and again, for example , inputText01 turns to inputText011 if somehow, I need to resubmit the form because of required fields that are not populated. Note that i can have name parameter with number (like inputText0).

Comment: I used `v.replace(/\d/g,'')` and as long as possible I will try not to use request paramater name with numbers. :))

Comment: I used data.serialize() to pass values. Ok, thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `:first` selector? Here is the documentation from jQuery website: https://api.jquery.com/first-selector.

Comment: Hi, but I also set not only for the first input field.